# Android APK errors during install

Tags: android, xamarin

When publishing our solution to an APK using the Archive Manager, the APK is not being installed.

When I tap on the APK on the device using ES File Explorer, there is a message that states: "App not installed"

Here are the versions I am using:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2012 Version 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL
>   Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01055
>
> Installed Version: Premium
>
> Visual C# 2012   04941-004-0043007-02064 Microsoft Visual C# 2012
>
> Xamarin   4.2.2.6 (27a9b40) Visual Studio extension to enable
>   development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.
>
> Xamarin.Android   7.0.2.42 (501e63c) Visual Studio extension to enable
>   development for Xamarin.Android.
>
> Xamarin.iOS   10.3.1.7 (8b53676) Visual Studio extension to enable
>   development for Xamarin.iOS.

Does anyone have a way to see exactly why the App was not installed?

When I use the Device Logging, I see the below output

```
01-11 15:35:10.734 I/InstallAppProgress(18156): Finished installing com.afs.dsd_mobile
01-11 15:35:12.070 I/ActivityManager(  454): START u0 {dat=/storage/emulated/0/Download/com.afs.dsd_mobile.apk cmp=com.estrongs.android.pop/.app.ShowDialogActivity (has extras)} from pid 17445
01-11 15:35:12.508 I/ActivityManager(  454): Displayed com.estrongs.android.pop/.app.ShowDialogActivity: +362ms
01-11 15:35:13.367 I/ActivityManager(  454): START u0 {cmp=com.estrongs.android.pop/.app.OpenRecomm (has extras)} from pid 17445
01-11 15:35:13.484 W/ResourceType(17445): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
01-11 15:35:13.523 I/ActivityManager(  454): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/com.afs.dsd_mobile.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity} from pid 17445
01-11 15:35:13.625 I/AppSecurityPermissions(18156): Ignoring unknown permission:com.symbol.emdk.permission.EMDK
01-11 15:35:13.625 I/AppSecurityPermissions(18156): Ignoring unknown permission:com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY
01-11 15:35:13.625 I/AppSecurityPermissions(18156): Ignoring unknown permission:android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT
01-11 15:35:13.625 W/AppSecurityPermissions(18156): Could'nt retrieve shared user id for:com.afs.dsd_mobile
01-11 15:35:13.750 I/ActivityManager(  454): Displayed com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity: +221ms (total +364ms)
01-11 15:35:15.195 I/ActivityManager(  454): START u0 {dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/com.afs.dsd_mobile.apk cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.InstallAppProgress (has extras)} from pid 18156
01-11 15:35:15.320 D/dalvikvm(18156): GC_CONCURRENT freed 96K, 3% free 6960K/7120K, paused 13ms+11ms, total 56ms
01-11 15:35:15.328 D/dalvikvm(18156): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 3ms
01-11 15:35:15.375 W/ActivityManager(  454): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/com.afs.dsd_mobile.apk
01-11 15:35:15.445 I/ActivityManager(  454): Displayed com.android.packageinstaller/.InstallAppProgress: +205ms
01-11 15:35:25.914 W/ActivityManager(  454): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/com.afs.dsd_mobile.apk
01-11 15:35:25.914 I/PackageManager(  454): Copying native libraries to /data/app-lib/vmdl-1977729985
01-11 15:35:28.109 W/PackageParser(  454): Exception reading /data/app/vmdl-1977729985.tmp
01-11 15:35:28.109 W/PackageParser(  454): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-11 15:35:28.109 W/PackageParser(  454):  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.collectCertificates(PackageParser.java:633)
01-11 15:35:28.109 W/PackageParser(  454):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:7886)
01-11 15:35:28.109 W/PackageParser(  454):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.access$1900(PackageManagerService.java:172)
01-11 15:35:28.109 W/PackageParser(  454):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$5.run(PackageManagerService.java:6018)
01-11 15:35:28.109 W/PackageParser(  454):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-11 15:35:28.109 W/PackageParser(  454):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-11 15:35:28.109 W/PackageParser(  454):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-11 15:35:28.109 W/PackageParser(  454):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
01-11 15:35:28.406 D/dalvikvm(  454): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1663K, 34% free 16718K/25044K, paused 10ms+12ms, total 171ms
01-11 15:35:28.414 D/InstallAppProgress(18156): Installation error code: -102
```

Comment: Look at `logcat` via `adb logcat` ... A wild guess would be it is not build with the correct `ABI` for the device that you are installing it to.

Comment: When using the Device Logging, I see a security permissions error:             **01-11 15:32:58.422 W/AppSecurityPermissions(18156): Could'nt retrieve shared user id for:com.afs.dsd_mobile**

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I neglected to sign the APK by using the distribute functionality. Once I was able to sign with my key, the APK installs successfully.

Comment: wrote an answer that includes more details in case others run into this same issue (I did)

Answer (score 0):

To clarify for other people...

You have to do three things to build an APK and run it on a device.

1. Build as Release (not as Debug)
2. Archive and then sign the apk by right clicking the project, selecting archive, then selecting distribute.
3. Put device in developer mode, then download apk and run it.